# Robot Framework test run on docker containers

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile, robotframework

I have a problem running RFWK tests on docker containers, usually it was done on dedicated servers where was ssh option (SSH is needed). But now I wanted to run them locally on my local docker containers. But I don't know, how to skip the ssh connection. Should I make some changes to dockerfile or slightly change tests init?

Comment: What happens when you try to connect in ssh from inside your container?

Comment: RFWK tests uses "ssh user@workstation(or sth)" to connect to environment. In case of docker i don't know how to create connection like this.

Comment: Could you please print the output of the ssh command you run?

Comment: From eclipse FRWK i get sth like   [ ERROR ] *** Check credentials: user and password
[ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user.  Because i can't get access to docker container through e.g ssh user@container

Comment: Add more details about your setup. This gives no idea as to how you are executing the tests? what is the whole setup like

Comment: ok, so my RFWK tests are based on connecting to remote environment through ssh and are doing some things there (basically run some cmd's and checks the output). RFWK tests uses our internal company lib to create ssh connection. I wanted to create docker container, connect via ssh to this container and run tests on my local machine not remote one.

Comment: I've created simple image which is based on ubuntu, does apt-get update and openssh. I've found some tutorials but those methods weren't working.
Simply I want eg run on my workstation cmd "ssh root@localhost:(container port)" and be able to run commands like mkdir, cp, mv.

Comment: @Pat, what is your base image used for robotframework? what python packages have installed in it?

Comment: @Rao I wanted to run robotframework localy.